# countdown timer stop (how to do in this situation)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i try to do countdown timer. But **i get a double timer** on the third click,and the more and more after next click... I am racking my brain trying to figure how do this. Can you help me?

```js
function goTime(){
 // in thist funcion we change color of button on click,also it will help me stop timer
  let color = $('#time').css('background-color');
  
  if (color=='rgb(0, 0, 0)'){
    $('#time').css('background-color','grey');
    let colors = setInterval(timer, 1000); 
    //start countdown timer
  }
  
  if(color=='rgb(128, 128, 128)'){ 
    $('#time').css('background-color','black');
  }

}

//this funcion starts every 1 second
function timer() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('time');
  let color = $('#time').css('background-color'); 
  if (color=='rgb(128, 128, 128)'){
  elem.innerText --;
  }
}
```

```css
#time{
  margin-top:15px;
  background: black; 
  color:white;
  padding: 6px; 
  width: 123px; 
  height: auto;
  margin-left:-3px;

  text-align: center;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 65px;
  line-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <p id="time" onclick="goTime()">90</p>
```

Comment: It keeps adding multiple intervals - all of which are changing the timer. You need to make sure that every time the function goTime is called, you clear the previous interval using clearInterval call at the very start of the function - before creating a new interval below.

Comment: How do this? if I write "clearInterval(colors);" in any of the functions, they won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the interval in your JavaScript file as follows every time in the goTime function:

```
var colors;

function goTime(){
  clearInterval(colors)
 // in thist funcion we change color of button on click,also it will help me stop timer
  let color = $('#time').css('background-color');
  
  if (color=='rgb(0, 0, 0)'){
    $('#time').css('background-color','grey');
    colors = setInterval(timer, 1000); 
    //start countdown timer
  }
  
  if(color=='rgb(128, 128, 128)'){ 
    $('#time').css('background-color','black');
  }

}

//this funcion starts every 1 second
function timer() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('time');
  let color = $('#time').css('background-color'); 
  if (color=='rgb(128, 128, 128)'){
  elem.innerText --;
  }
}
```